# Building an array with 10 elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

1. Try to build a program with an array with 10 elements and initialize it, get maximum, minimum, average and sum of those numbers. Print out the result.
2. Build a function to sort it with ascend order by using bubble sorting algorithm or other sorting algorithm. Print out the result.
3. Modify the above code into OOP style: Build a class to integrate all above functions into the class. Make one or two object to print out the result.

This is my attempt on the problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void bubble_sorting(int a1[]);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int size=10;
    int data[100]={11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12};
    int min, max, avg, sum;
//  cout<<"Enter the array size:"<<endl;
//  cin>>size;
    for(int i1=0;i1<size;i1++)
    {
//     cin>>data[i1];
//      data[i1]=rand();
       if(i1==0)
       {
          min=data[i1];
          max=data[i1];
          sum=data[i1];
       }
       else
       {
          if(data[i1]<min)min=data[i1];    
          if(data[i1]>max)max=data[i1];
          sum=sum+data[i1];
       }
    } 
    cout<<"The Min number is:"<<min<<endl;
    cout<<"The Max number is:"<<max<<endl;
    cout<<"The average number is:"<<sum/size<<endl;
    cout<<"The sum number is:"<<sum<<endl;
    bubble_sorting(data);
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sorting(int a1[])
{

      int i2;
      int t1;
      for(int i1=0;i1<10;i1++)
      {
           i2=1;
           for(i2=1;i2<10;i2++)
           {
               if(a1[i2]<a1[i2-1])
               {
                   t1=a1[i2];
                   a1[i2]=a1[i2-1];
                   a1[i2-1]=t1;
               }

           } 

      }
      cout<<"The data after sorting is:"<<endl;
      for(int i1=0;i1<10;i1++)
      {
          cout<<a1[i1]<<" ";
      } 
      cout<<endl;
}
```

What's the best way to construct the bubble sort?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can you please add your question

Comment: Whats the best way to construct the bubble sort?

Comment: I think you will find that checking bubble sort in **Wikipedia** will yield pretty strong suggestions about how to "construct" it. I have intentionally not provided a link to Wikipedia in this comment. Finding Wikipedia yourself is a good first learning exercise.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: The hostility is real on this website lol

Comment: You posted code but you didn't tell us what's wrong with it. Your code looks like an attempt at doing bubble sort, but then you ask how to do it, so understandably we're left a bit confused. Doesn't it compile? Does it crash / throw an exception? Does it produce the incorrect output? In any of these cases, please describe the problem in as much detail as possible. Beyond that, you're likely to find plenty of implementations of bubble sort online, so any runtime problem encountered should be fairly easy to fix by comparing your code to another implementation, or just stepping through your code.

Comment: I see, im sorry if i confused anyone..Im new to this website!

Answer (score 1):

Since you've made a fair fist of the first two parts of the question, viz implementing the stats and the bubble sort, here is some help with the third:

- Move the sorting and stats into 1 or 2 classes. I've been lazy and implemented just one, although more correctly, the concerns of sorting and determining the basic stats could be separated into 2 classes (SRP of SOLID).
- Move your data into fields of the class, and expose these as properties via `get` / `set` methods.
- Expose functionality such as sorting as methods
- In general, use the STL template classes for storing collections, such as `vector`
- As per the suggested Wiki article, there are optimisations for the bubble sort.

Other minor points

- Initialize your aggregates (`sum, avg, min, max`) as soon as possible, not in a branch in a loop.
- Try not to hard code constants, such as the size of the array, and especially don't repeat the constant in more than one place - this makes the code fragile to change. With the `vector`, the size is an inherent property of the collection.
- The average can't be an `int`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class BubbleSorter
{
public:
    BubbleSorter(const vector<int>& unsortedNumbers)
        : _min(INT_MAX), _max(INT_MIN), _sum(0)
    {
        _numbers = unsortedNumbers;
        calculateStats();
    }

    int getMin()
    {
        return _min;
    }
    int getMax()
    {
        return _max;
    }
    int getSum()
    {
        return _sum;
    }
    double getAvg()
    {
        return _avg;
    }
    const vector<int>& getNumbers()
    {
        return _numbers;
    }

    void bubbleSort()
    {
        int n = _numbers.size();
        bool swapped;
        do
        {
            swapped = false;
            for(vector<int>::size_type i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if(_numbers[i] < _numbers[i-1])
                {
                    int t1=_numbers[i];
                    _numbers[i]=_numbers[i-1];
                    _numbers[i-1]=t1;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            } 
        } while (swapped);
    }

private:
    vector<int> _numbers;
    int _min, _max, _sum;
    double _avg; // not int!

    void calculateStats()
    {
        for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < _numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            if(_numbers[i] < _min)
                _min = _numbers[i];    
            if(_numbers[i] > _max)
                _max=_numbers[i];
            _sum = _sum + _numbers[i];
        } 
        _avg = (double)_sum/_numbers.size();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int data[] = {11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12};
    vector<int> unsorted(begin(data), end(data));
    BubbleSorter sorter(unsorted);

    cout << "The Min number is:" << sorter.getMin() << endl;
    cout << "The Max number is:" << sorter.getMax() << endl;
    cout << "The average number is:"<< sorter.getAvg() <<endl;
    cout << "The sum of numbers is:" << sorter.getSum() <<endl;

    sorter.bubbleSort();

    cout<<"The data after sorting is:"<<endl;

    vector<int> sorted = sorter.getNumbers();
    for(int i=0; i < sorted.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << sorted[i] << " ";
    } 
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```